# Сайт по руководству в создании браузерных игр

Tags: php, html, css

Хочу создать простую он-лайн игру на php+mysql html css в текстовом виде, что-то вроде [этой](http://league17.ru) или [этой](http://pokelegenda.ru). Кто знает сайт, что посвящен этой теме, киньте, пожалуйста, ссылку.

Comment: Да вы уже запарили минусить !! За что?

Comment: http://gcup.ru/forum/6-1634-1
посмотрите тут или доканывайте гугл на тему - создание текстовой игры (если правильно понял выражение "в текстовом виде")

Comment: АгА я знаю этот сайт , спасибо =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

маскимум что вы сможете найти в интеренете это:
1 - уроки и статьи как пользоваться той или иной технологией(введение - продолжение - мастер класс)
2 - очень обобщенные и не содержательные статьи о gamedev в целом.

чтобы написать игру - надо думать самому от начала до конца.. готовых и уж тем более разжеванных решений нет!!

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку сегодня технология не стоит на месте, я вам предлогаю попробовать сделать Вашу онлайн игру, по технологии html5 а именно canvas+js. Уже существуют такие игры http://html5games.com/, а как создать их можно поискать в гугле. К примеру, нашел у человека в блоге: [html5Development](http://zxcat.ru/2011/01/08/sozdanie-igry-na-html5-chast-1/). Так же в [хабрахабр](http://habrahabr.ru/) можете поискать, там много интересных статей на данную тему можно найти.

Comment: Пробывал я, html canvas пока (увы) не катит, даже 2d игру серьезнее танчиков каких-то сделать практически нереально...<br>
Canvas целесообразно использовать разве что для рендеринга, не более<br>
Ну а WebGL штука поинтереснее, но и знаний требует, мягко говоря, побольше, да и поддержка пока ужасна и когда будет принят WebGL как стандарт (и будет ли принят, еще и Билл со своим сильверлайтом >_<) - большой вопрос

Comment: http://chrome.angrybirds.com/ - создана по технологии html5

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы этот сайт [gamedev.ru](http://www.gamedev.ru/) специализируется на этой тематике, есть и иностранный аналог gamedev.net.

А еще есть [ролик](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=box2d%20raphael&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwhatdoyouknow.webdirections.org%2Fvideos%2Fnewton-js-box2d-raphael&ei=2CauTvuSLcOe-waa6LzlDw&usg=AFQjCNHlx0_LXWiq86LDFZdUdZfMLEIzwg&sig2=dC5S0GDPwD5FLVzWvieOzQ) интересный по использованию RaphaelJS + box2d.

Comment: да GameDev на обоих языках - тематетический ресурс посвященный вопросам создания игр(как и множество других посвященных опреденным средствам), но там лишь то, что я написал выше, а с вопросом как у топик стартера его просто затроллят на обоих ресурсах, ровно как и на любом другом...